# Check user login form using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm kinda new to this php language. I seem to have a problem with checking my table in the database for the user. It just goes successful all the time and even though it is not the right password. It just goes to "admin/index-admin.php". Please help me..

My Codes :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <table align="center">
              <tr>
                      <td align="center"><h2>Administrator Login</h2></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td align="left">Username : </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td align="left">Password : </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td>
              </tr>
      </table>
      </form>

      <?php
            $user = $_REQUEST['username'];
            $pass = $_REQUEST['password'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=".$user." AND password=".$pass."";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(count($result)>0)
            {  
                    header('Location: admin/index-admin.php');

                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
                    echo "alert('You are logged In Successfully.')";
                    echo "</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                    echo "Invalid Username or Password.";
            }
       ?>
```

and if i use jquery mobile with php will there be a difference with my problem? will it be the same problem?

Thanks for helping...

oh and my database is somewhat like this :

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("","",""); ==> //i just left them blank in purpose..
if(!$conn)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}

$db = mysql_select_db("",$conn); ==> //i just left them blank in purpose..
if(!$db)
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: You should not use mysql_ functions since they are deprecated but try this and see if it works: 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){

Comment: http://us1.php.net/mysql_query. Even if the query fails, $result will return something (possibly boolean FALSE) so the count will always be > 0

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'";` missing single quotes; try that on for size now.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Please read about PDO, and web application security

Comment: Sidenote: It's not recommended storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: @Maximus2012 i tried, but the "Invalid username or password" thing is visible all the time. and it just stays in the same page. it does not redirect to admin/index-admin.php.

Comment: use exit function after header function call and remove the echo script alert part after that since you are trying to mix and match php with javascript which is sort of mutually exclusive in this case.

Comment: Instead of `if(count($result)>0)` try `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)` @LyndonBrozCañeteTonelete if it's still giving you problems.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried yours but it always ends up "Invalid username/password" and when refreshed it shows up first..

Comment: See my answer below and read the footnotes @LyndonBrozCañeteTonelete

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your variables within single quotes in your query: (also use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent sql injection)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($user)."' AND password='".mysqli_real_escape_string($pass)."'";
```

You need to fetch rows from resultset:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($row)) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: also you might want to use an if ($_POST['submit']){ before your php so that it only checks it if you have submitted your form.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend you use a different password storage method. Some are posted in my footnotes.

Try this `mysqli_*` method which worked for me.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <table align="center">
              <tr>
                      <td align="center"><h2>Login</h2></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td align="left">Username: </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td align="left">Password: </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                      <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td>
              </tr>
      </table>
      </form>

<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$mysqli = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_REQUEST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_REQUEST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row["username"]==$user && $row["password"]==$pass){
    echo "You are a validated user.";

    // header('Location: admin/index-admin.php');
    }

else{
    die("Sorry Jack");
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>
```

**Added method:**

Create a column called `approved` using "YES" or "NO" as a value in order to temporarily deny access to those who have been marked as "NO".

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass' AND approved='YES'";
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Passwords

I noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: i tried correct info and the result is same page, not in admin/index-admin.php.. and i tried incorrect info and the result is blank page..

Comment: Did you copy my exact code? Plus make sure you have the correct columns named. I tested this before submitting. @LyndonBrozCañeteTonelete I used `mysqli_*` and not `mysql_*` so if you're still using your old DB login, don't. Simply replace the `xxx` with your own credentials. This works.

Comment: I tend to think that the problem is in your `admin/index-admin.php` file and not my code. I don't know what you have in there, so you'll have to make sure that things match. @LyndonBrozCañeteTonelete

Comment: what data type should I use in approved?

Comment: I used just a VARCHAR, doesn't have to be long; it's going to be text (YES or NO) type of thing, so `VARCHAR (5)` should be ok. If you feel also that my answer has solved the issue, consider accepting it so it doesn't remain in the unanswered category. @LyndonBrozCañeteTonelete

Comment: I don't know how you're using it, but I'll say it again; it worked for me with no problems. I can't help you anymore than I already have/tried. @LyndonBrozCañeteTonelete

Comment: if i say that, i'm making a jquery mobile web application, will there be a difference?